iam using lubuntu destro.while i was trying to install anything it shows the following:-
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_lubuntu_noble-noble.list (Component) E: The list of sources could not be read.

This question is similar to: How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error is telling you that someone using sudo writes has created the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_lubuntu_noble-noble.list which has an error within it at line 1.  We're limited to knowing only details you provide in your question, where you've not shown us the contents; but that file needs to be corrected on line 1.  Note that subsequent lines may contain errors too, as the error checking stops at the first line containing an error.
